# After waking up the phone my activity recovers in wrong orientation

Tags: android, android-activity

In my android application an activity must hold only in landscape orientation. For that I modified an activity-tag in my file AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="com.pckg.MyProj"
        android:label="MyProject"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

It works correctly, but just until I lock the phone and then wake it up again. Sometimes the picture recovers normally, but sometimes it fails in the following way. If before locking it looks like this
[image]

then after waking up it looks like
[image]

All it looks like the phone wakes up in portrait orientation and fit the image to the screen, but then it reminds that portrait orientation is denied and tries to redress it's wrong just rotating the image. Resulting image is correspondingly compressed and cut; an empty rectangle remains to the right of it. I had this pretty effect on a few different devices.

Have you any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is found. The problem was in my attempts to economize a few OpenGL operations.

In the code responsible for drawing I never change the OpenGL viewport and matrices, so I decided to set them once in the method onResume() and never care about it. The following method was called in onResume() (in OpenGL thread):

```
public void on initState {
    GL10 gl = glGraphics.getGL();
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glOrthof(x1, x2, y1, y2, 1, -1);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
}
```

When the user unlocks the phone, the application wakes up immideately calling the method onResume (and therefore initState()). But at this moment the screen may be still in portrait orientation, so the method initState() set OpenGL viewport and matrices accordingly to the portrait screen. Then the orientation changes to landscape. The activity appears in correct orientation but is built by OpenGL being in the state set in the portrait orientation.

The solution is to put the method initState() to the drawing method and thus set it every time when the activity is drawn.

It is interesting (and tangling) that the effect appears only if lock/unlock takes place. Going out to the phone menu is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to inflate Fragment dynamically in onResume() ?

Comment: attempts to set activity orientation in the method onResume() do not help, because
1) it's enough to put corresponding attribute to the activity tag in the file AndroidManifest.xml once instead;
2) there is really all right with activity orientation (see the solution below)